# Why the colors of comments and class/function descriptor are the same in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using the `Predawn` color theme in VS Code. I use two different servers to work on my codes. In one of them, the color of comments written by `""" """` in python is *light green* and the one written by `#` is *gray*, which is exactly what I want.

[image]

However, in another server, the colors of both types are *gray*.

[image]

I couldn't find where in the setting to fix it and differentiate these two comments. (I use the remote to connect those servers, so the VS Code is the same for both)

Comment: Are the vs code and plugin versions the same in both the servers?

Comment: Yes. I use the remote to connect to both. So it is basically the same VS Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this code to `settings.json` (can be found after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>) to solve the problem:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "textMateRules": [
      {           
          "scope": [
              "string.quoted.multi.python",
              "string.quoted.double.block.python",
              "string.quoted.triple",
              "string.quoted.docstring.multi.python",
              "string.quoted.docstring.multi.python punctuation.definition.string.begin.python",
              "string.quoted.docstring.multi.python punctuation.definition.string.end.python",
              "string.quoted.docstring.multi.python constant.character.escape.python"
          ],          
          "settings": {
              "foreground": "#BDDCDC" //change to your preference
          }       
      }
  ]
  },
```

The most important scope for me was `"string.quoted.double.block.python"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to your `settings.json`, you can change the color of the **docstring** comments using

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope":"string.quoted.docstring.multi.python",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#00ff00" // change this
            }
        }
    ]
},
```

You can also change the color of regular comments by using

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "comments": "#ff0000"
},
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is not about changing the color of comments. This is having two colors for two types of comments. Comment made by `#` or by `""" """`.

Comment: `""` creates strings, not comments. You might be *using* strings as comments (you probably shouldn't), but a syntax highlighter probably isn't equipped to determine which strings are which. (Unless it specifically recognizes strings in doc-string position to highlight differently.)

Comment: @chepner As you can see in the other screenshot, it differentiates them. So, it has the ability to do that. Also, it is a common practice to use `""" """` for class/function descriptor. No one uses `#` to comment on that. In the code, if I use one double-quotation(`"`), which is how we write strings, it is in *green*. However, if I use three double-quotations (`"""`), which is used for function descriptor, it is in *gray*.

Comment: @Hadij I updated my post to show how to differentiate between the two types of comment. It does work, but for some reason it doesn't change the color of `"""`.

Comment: @abnathan Thank you. It worked for me in the one that was already *green*. But the one which was *gray* still does not change! It seems that something does not let it get updated. Do we have a local (server-specific) `settings.json`?

Comment: @Hadij I don't have a server-specific `settings.json`, but you can create a `.vscode` [folder](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_workspace-settings) and create a `settings.json` with these settings there. Maybe that might fix the issue.

Comment: @abnathan Thank you. I tried it, but unfortunately, it didn't work. It seems that something is overwriting the settings and I am not sure what it is.